# What is meant by the linear mapping $T$ is entirely and uniquely determined on $V$?

Tags: linear-algebra

$$
\newcommand{\F}{\mathbb{F}}
\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb{R}}
\newcommand{\a}{\mathbf{a}}
\newcommand{\b}{\mathbf{b}}
\newcommand{\c}{\mathbf{c}}
\newcommand{\e}{\mathbf{e}}
\newcommand{\u}{\mathbf{u}}
\newcommand{\v}{\mathbf{v}}
\newcommand{\w}{\mathbf{w}}
\newcommand{\x}{\mathbf{x}}
\newcommand{\y}{\mathbf{y}}
\newcommand{\z}{\mathbf{z}}
\newcommand{\A}{\mathbf{A}}
\newcommand{\B}{\mathbf{B}}
\newcommand{\C}{\mathbf{C}}
\newcommand{\rank}{\textbf{rank}}
\newcommand{\0}{\mathbf{0}}
\newcommand{\1}{\mathbf{1}}
\newcommand{\U}{\mathrm{U}}
\newcommand{\V}{\mathrm{V}}
\newcommand{\W}{\mathrm{W}}
\newcommand{\L}{\mathcal{L}}
$$

With reference to [a similar post here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4114034/is-a-linear-map-uniquely-determined-on-v-or-on-a-basis-of-v), I cannot fully understand the terminology "$T$ determined on $\V$". To elaborate, the theorem states:

Let $\V$ and $\W$ be vector spaces over $\F$.

Suppose $\v_1, ..., \v_n$ is a **basis** of $\V$ and $\w_1, ..., \w_n$ be a set of **arbitrary vectors** in $\W$. Then there exists an **unique linear map** $T: \V \to \W$ such that

$$
T(\v_j) = \w_j , \quad \forall j = 1, ..., n
$$

---

The author mentioned:

> The existence part of the next result means that we can find a linear map
> that takes on whatever values we wish on the vectors in a basis. The uniqueness
> part of the next result means that a linear map is completely determined by its
> values on a basis.

I tried to reconcile this with an example from the link above.

Suppose I have a transformation $T: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$. At this point I do not know the exact mapping $T$ yet.

Pick a basis $B=\{\e_1=(1,0), \e_2=(0,1) \}$.

Then $T$ is **completely** specified by the values $\w_1=T(\e_1),\w_2=T(\e_2)$. At this point, I know such a $T$ must exist and be uniquely determined by the theorem above. This is still vague to me, as I do not understand if $T$ is determined by the basis of $\V$ alone (much confusion with the wording of "determined on $\V$".

So I read on and see the elaboration from the post, the OP mentioned that now he understood that once $T$ is determined **by $\w_j$ on $\v_j$**, then this $T$ is unique on $\V$. My understanding of **determined** is that we need to know both $\v_1, \v_2$ (the basis vectors of $\V = \mathbb{R}^2$) and the **output** $\w_1 = T(\e_1), \w_2 = T(\e_2)$. Consequently, we need to pick any vectors $\w_1, \w_2 \in \W$, say $\w_1 = (1, 1), \w_2 = (2, 0)$ then only can we say that this **particular mapping $T$** is uniquely and entirely determined by $\w_j$ on $\v_j$?

Is my understanding correct? It will be great if I can have a concrete example to illustrate the two points the author mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$S, T\in \mathcal{L}(V, W) $

Then $S=T $ iff $Sv=Tv$ ,$\forall v\in V$

Now, $V, W$ are not just ordinary set and $S, T$ not only ordinary mapping. $V, W$ has a rich algebraic structure - vector space and $S, T$ are linear map. This makes our life easy.

$S=T$  iff $ Sv=Tv, \forall v\in \mathcal{B}_V$

Where $\mathcal{B}_V$ is a basis of $V$.

In other words, if two linear map agrees on a basis of the domain space , then the agrees on the whole domain.

Proof is not difficult,

Take, $v\in V $

$v=\sum_{j\in J }c_j v_j$ where $c_j=0 $ for all but finitely many $j$'s and $v_j \in \mathcal{B}_V$

Now, $\begin{align}Tv = T(\sum_{j\in J }c_j v_j)  &=\sum_{j\in J }c_jTv_j \\&=\sum_{j\in J }c_jSv_j= Sv \end{align}$

So, if you can specify a map $T$ linearly on $\mathcal{B}_V$, it can be extended uniquely and linearly.

Suppose, $\mathcal{B}_V=\{v_j : j\in J\}$

$T:\mathcal{B}_V \to W $

$Tv_j=w_j$

Then, $\exists \hat{T} \in \mathcal{L}(V,W) $ unique and $\hat{T}|_{\mathcal{B}_V}=T$

$\hat{T}v=\hat{T}\sum_{j=1}^{n} c_jv_j=\sum_{j=1}^{n} c_j \hat{T} v_j=\sum_{j=1}^{n} c_j Tv_j=\sum_{j=1}^{n} c_jw_j=w$

Where, $v=\sum_{j=1}^{n} c_jv_j$ and $w=\sum_{j=1}^{n} c_jw_j$

Comment: Do you mind giving me a concrete example as well? I can understand the proof but is still shaky with the question I asked, more concretely, T is only uniquely and entirely determined if and only if both basis vectors v's and its corresponding w output are defined, and not only when V is defined.